# groovy script to get private Bitbucket Branches by making an api call

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, bitbucket-server

I want to show all the branch names dynamically using a groovy script by making an api call to bitbucket private repo. I am following this article [link](https://mgrebenets.github.io/mobile%20ci/2015/02/08/bitbucket-branches-job-dsl).In this article top is using https , instead I like to use ssh.

```
String baseUrl = "https://bitbucket.org/api"
String version = "1.0"
String organization = "i4niac"
String repository = "mirepoix"


String branchesUrl = [baseUrl, version, "repositories", organization, repository, "branches"].join("/")


String username = "i4niac"
String password = "mypassword"
// Create authorization header using Base64 encoding
String userpass = username + ":" + password;
String basicAuth = "Basic " + javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(userpass.getBytes());
// Create URL
URL url = branchesUrl.toURL()
// Open connection
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection()
// Set authorization header
connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth)
// Open input stream
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()
// Get JSON output
def branchesJson = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(inputStream.text)
// Close the stream
inputStream.close()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "private Bitbucket repository"?  If it's really private, that would mean the public should not have read/write access to it.

Comment: public GitHub would not allow me to write to your repo and vice versa , unless it is via PR

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/command-line-rest/)

As per Bitbucket API documentation -

To use a REST API, your application will make an HTTP or HTTPS request and parse the response so I highly doubt if you can use ssh URL